# What does "Tomcat Endpoint" Waiting On Object Monitor mean?

Tags: java, http, sockets, tomcat, jboss

Reviewing a stack trace of a non-responsive web-app, I realized that some of the data did not match how-I-thought-tomcat-works.

**Context**

The application is getting hit in rapid succession for a slow url. These requests seem to pile up, i.e. form a traffic jam in the app server. Logging shows that the number of threads/http connectors have maxed out (number of busy threads has crept up to to the maxThreads value of 120).

- Jboss 4.2.2
- Uses a variation of tomcat 6.0 called 'jboss-web'

**The question**

Many of the threads are "doing something"--i.e. reading from the database, writing to the output stream etc...Yet over 50 of the threads are "waiting on the connector to provide a new socket" (From the comments)

What exactly does this mean to the non-socket programmer?

**My prior assumptions: wrong**

I had assumed that each http thread would 'do its own work'--get the request, do some work, and write the response -- and *not* need to wait for anything.

so...

- What's going on? Could someone clarify the socket-ish stuff?
- What implication does such a bottleneck for the tomcat settings? (i.e. increase this setting, decrease that one, etc.)

** Stack Trace **

```
"http-0.0.0.0-80-90" daemon prio=6 tid=0x695e1400 nid=0x24c in Object.wait() [0x6e8cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x09c34480> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:416)
    - locked <0x09c34480> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:442)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

*Code fragment from Tomcat's org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIOEndpoint*

```
     /**
     * Process an incoming TCP/IP connection on the specified socket.  Any
     * exception that occurs during processing must be logged and swallowed.
     * <b>NOTE</b>:  This method is called from our Connector's thread.  We
     * must assign it to our own thread so that multiple simultaneous
     * requests can be handled.
     *
     * @param socket TCP socket to process
     */
    synchronized void assign(Socket socket) {

        // Wait for the Processor to get the previous Socket
        while (available) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        // Store the newly available Socket and notify our thread
        this.socket = socket;
        available = true;
        notifyAll();

    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maxNumThreads setting doesn't affect the servlet container's performance rather than requiring bigger heap and more cpu cycles (if your threads get activated). However, every time you modify that setting to a number bigger than 150, you might think of a bottleneck in your application.

The web server is not designed to handle more than 100 simultaneous requests. If you do find yourself in such a situation, consider clustering. I see you are using jbossweb and there is a really nice article here:

http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-jboss

However, as I don't think you have more than 100 simultaneous requests, I think it is a bottleneck in your applications. Things to check are your jdbc driver, the version of jdk you use, the tomcat version (in your case 6.0). Requests to your application should finish in less than 1 second - network latency (and even that is a way too huge delay ) and if you find they take more, it is probably somewhere in your code. Do you manually close/open your database connections, do you use efficient threading in the background, do you use JMS. That are the things to look at usually. The other might be a bug in your particular servlet container version.

P.S If you do decide to use a higher number of max threads, it might make sense to decrease/increase the  thread stack size and see how it affects performance. If you have long lived threads( which should not be), you might want to increase the stack size. If you have short - lived threads, try decreasing the stack size to preserve a bit memory.
-Xss is the flag.

Also, i just saw the jboss AS version you are using. Check that also. Now that I look at your symptoms, I believe your problem is somewhere in the configuration files.